# Does K0s support Helm v.3?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, k0s

I am trying to use helm charts with k0s.

Having my own helm-charts app, I would like to create a local repo. But I cannot use the `serve` command since I am using version: 3.5.4 and the serve command had been ditched for security concerns.

I am not sure now how to create a local repo ? and where can I find tutorials or examples ?

Also, how to deploy my chart in k0s cluster ?

Answer (score 2):

I would try to use [ChartMuseum](https://github.com/helm/chartmuseum) instead. You can follow the [docs to create a local filesystem chart](https://chartmuseum.com/docs/#using-with-local-filesystem-storage).

You simply deploy the same way as with helm v2. Make sure you [add the chart repo](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_repo_add/) and you have [kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/) configured to point to the cluster that you want to talk to so that `~/.kube/config` has the right configuration.

Comment: I merely need to have a local system directory where my charts could be loaded from it. ChartMuseum is a good option indeed but it lack any examples or tutorials. The link you put is very short in description. But thanks anyway. I fyou could direct me to an example it would be appreicate it

Comment: it does have a guide: https://chartmuseum.com/docs/#installing-chartsinto-kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does, you can also utilize k8slens.dev to easily deploy helm charts to your Kubernetes clusters. Regardless of the distro..

Comment: I am working on Linux so the graphical interface would be wasted. Still a good solution for deployments